# Change of button look on touch, not just on click

Tags: android, button, colors, onclick, ontouchlistener

If you register an OnClickListener and "click" a button, it gets blue and the font white (at least in my case). But if I register an OnTouchListener that's not the case. How do I change that? I need the OnTouch because I want to send signals as long as the Button is pressed.

I want every button to look like this: pressed button as it should look like.

But the ones for which I work with an OnTouchListener instead of an OnClickListener it looks like this at the moment (done programmaticaly, because otherwise it would look like an unpressed button): ugly look of pressed button.

But this is ugly.

How can I apply exactly the standard look of a pressed button programmaticaly?

The code to make an ugly button:

```
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
view.invalidate();
```

---

I want every button to look like this:
[pressed button as it should look like](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/shot000001l.jpg/).

But the ones for which I work with an OnTouchListener instead of an OnClickListener it looks like this at the moment (done programmaticaly, because otherwise it would look like an unpressed button):
[ugly look of pressed button](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/401/shot000002l.jpg/).

But this is ugly.

How can I apply exactly the standard look of a pressed button programmaticaly?

The code to make an ugly button:

```
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
view.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should think of using selectors for the button...i hope i understood your question....